# MinGW C++ executable size, winpthreads, and TDM verses mingw-w64

Tags: c++, windows, gcc

I'm looking for a 64 bit C++ compiler that doesn't produce bloated executables.  Been using TDM-GCC 4.8 series and base compiles are in the 200 k range, apparently because winpthreads support is statically linked in.  I know the older MinGW C++ compilers, i.e., 4.3, 4.4 series just linked with system dll msvcrt.dll, and their base executable size was very small, in the 20 k range with C++ support.  Is it possible to not link winpthreads into TDM statically to eliminate that baggage?  I'm unfamiliar with MinGW -w64.  Would that be a better choice for me if I want the smallest possible executables?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this size difference matters for real C++ programs, but for what it worth I just build small app with mingw64 and size is in tens of kilobytes.

Mingw64, v5.3.0, 64bit, posix, seh exceptions